# Fault when linking phpmailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

In a recent project, I've been asked to link a reset password form to automatically send mail from an amazonAWS using SMTP php mailer. I've placed the calling code (mail->*) into a function. However since doing this, I seem to be receiving a **"Fatal error: Call to undefined method smtp::connected() in /var/www/html/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php on line 1530"**. I can't seem to find why this is happening and was wondering if anyone has seen a similar response.

Any help would be appreciated. The code is as follows

**smtp.php:**

```
    require_once('/var/www/html/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    class smtp {

        var $mail;

        function __construct () {
            $this->mail = new PHPMailer;
            $this->mail->isSMTP();
            $this->mail->Host = 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';
            $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $this->mail->Username = '---';
            $this->mail->Password = '---';
            $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $this->mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
            $this->mail->Port = 587;
            $this->mail->From = '---.com';
            $this->mail->FromName = '---';
            $this->mail->WordWrap = 50;
            $this->mail->isHTML(true);
            $this->mail->AltBody = 'Please use an HTML-enabled email client to view this message.';
        }

        function setSubject ($subject) {
            $this->mail->Subject = $subject;
        }

        function setBody ($body) {
            $this->mail->Body = stripslashes($body);
        }

        function sendTo ($to) {
            $this->mail->clearAddresses();
            $this->mail->addAddress($to);

            if (!$this->mail->send()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
```

**calling function:**

```
public function resetlink(){
        if($this->_passed){
            $pass = $this->_hash->getrand();
            if($this->_db->userValidate($_POST['email'])->getValidate()){
                $this->_db->update('---', array(
                        'username' => $_POST['email'], 
                        'value' => $pass

                ));

                $smtp = new smtp();
                $smtp->setSubject('sample subject');
                $smtp->setBody('sample body');
                $smtp->sendTo($_POST['email']);


            }else{
                echo "invalid email";
            }
        } return $this;
    }
```

**The function causing the issue is in class.phpmailer.php:**

```
if ($this->smtp->connected()) {
            return true;
        }
```

A test email was able to send when the code was run in procedural style, so the mail->* variables are correct. However ever since the code was put to run as a function, an error was found. Once again, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If PHPMailer uses a [class named SMTP](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php). You should give your own class a different name so they can't collide.

Comment: i can't believe i did't even look at this. Fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: The forthcoming PHPMailer 5.4 adds namespaces so this will no longer be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMailer contains and uses a [class named SMTP](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php).

If your class `smtp` is defined before it, it is possible that PHPMailer instanciates your SMTP class instead of its own, where the function is not defined.

You should give your own class a different name so they can't collide.